# How to link to specific id with href

Tags: html

For the better feeling i will put here some code:
Or if u prefer -> http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/5x3yp6Lb/

```html
<body>



<article class="tabs">

    <section id="tab1">
        <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum lacinia elit nec mi ornare et viverra massa pharetra. Phasellus mollis, massa sed suscipit pharetra, nunc tellus sagittis nunc, et tempus dui lorem a ipsum.</p>
        <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab2">next &#10151;</a></p>
    <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </section>
    
    <section id="tab2">
        <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
        <p>Fusce ullamcorper orci vel turpis vestibulum eu congue nisl euismod. Maecenas euismod, orci non tempus fermentum, leo metus lacinia lacus, nec ultrices quam ligula ac leo. Quisque tortor neque, vulputate quis ultricies ut, rhoncus mollis metus.</p>
        <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab3">next &#10151;</a></p>
    </section>
    
    <section id="tab3">
        <h2><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></h2>
        <p id="TARGET">This content appears on tab 3.</p>
        <p>Sed et diam eu ipsum scelerisque laoreet quis in nibh. Proin sodales augue lectus. Maecenas a lorem a mi congue pharetra. Sed sed risus in nisi venenatis condimentum. Donec ac consectetur arcu. Integer urna neque, rutrum at pretium eu.</p>
        <p class="tabnav"><a href="#tab1">next &#10151;</a></p>
    </section>

</article>



</body>
```

Okey so first of all imagine, this three sections(tab1, tab2, tab3) are more larger, like one section takes the full length of the screen or even more.
And now i want to have something like that:
When user clicks TEST on the first section (tab1), it should goes to the third section (tab3) but to the specific id = TARGET. So in situation when id=TARGET will be in middle of the third section, move from page1 to page3 should stop the screen in position when id = TARGET will be.

So:

```html
<a href="#tab3">>TEST</a>
```

is not enough

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working?

Comment: Okey so i want to link <a href="#tab3">TEST</a> But i want to be more specific and flip a user to <p id="TARGET">This content appears on tab 3.</p>

Comment: cuz <a href="#TARGET">TEST</a> will not works

Comment: What does "flip" mean? What **exactly** is not working? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't put relevant information in the comment section

Comment: I think - assuming by the names he used - that he wants to build a tab navigation. The thing is you will need to use some JavaScript for that. Or go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs and use a mature implementation

Answer (score -1):

to link to s specific id . use href ash shown

```
<a href="#IDNAME">TEST</a>
```

here is your id defination

```
<div id="IDNAME"> your div content where you link the the href</div>
```

but from your jsfiddle every thing looks ok what really do you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "fdhfhgdfdgfh"? Also, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does your code differ from the one that the OP currently uses?

Comment: never noticed the error. thats the content of the div

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it